# Google Drive API uploading file non-web based Python

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm not using an sdk just python requests to access Drive and I can write a file using v2 of the API but not v3.  I get a 404 error Not Found on this URL
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/{File-ID}?uploadType=media

this works when I change v3 to v2 but most of my work has been on v3 and I would like to be consistent. the doc does not show the file id in the url for v3 I have tried to put it in the header {'id': xxx} but this does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be expedient for you to check the [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) docs as 
they've made v3 more leaner and faster. According to this [Google video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&v=-7YH6rdR-tk) which uses Python, you can still use Drive v2.

> All update operations now use PATCH instead of PUT

Here's an [uploading code snippet](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/migrating-to-new-google-drive-api-v3.html) in v3 by Wesley Chun:

```
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
FILES = (

    ('hello.txt', None),
    ('hello.txt', 'application/vnd.google-apps.document')
)

for filename, mimeType in FILES:
    metadata = {'name': filename}
    if mimeType:
         metadata['mimeType'] = mimeType
    res = DRIVE.files().create(body=metadata, media_body=filename).execute()
    if res:
         print('Uploaded "%s" (%s)' % (filename, res['mimeType']))

 if res:

     MIMETYPE = 'application/pdf'
     data = DRIVE.files().export(fileId=res['id'], mimeType=MIMETYPE).execute()
     if data:
         fn = '%s.pdf' % os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
         with open(fn, 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(data)
         print('Downloaded "%s" (%s)') % (fn, MIMETYPE))
```

Comment: Ah.... Put has become patch, thanks for the info, I missed that migrate to v3 document. thanks

Comment: Dont forget to accept/upvote if the answer helped you. welcome

Comment: I just did but it says that my reputation is not high enough to make the counter tick up.  Thanks for the help....